# Troubleshooting Silverlight 5 and Ria services [Web-Services-AuthenticationService.svc does not exist]

Tags: iis-7, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I have two different versions of a Silverlight 5 project using Ria services.  Both work locally.  The older version (A) works when deployed to ISS7.  The new version (B) does not.  There is user/password authentication that fails for version B with the error:

- `Load operation failed for query 'Login'. the remote server returned an error: NotFound.`

Referencing various SO and MSDN posts over the past week, I have tried many troubleshooting techniques.  Adding error logging as suggested [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/186739.aspx/1/10) to the web.config results in the following being logged:

- `The service '/ClientBin/MyApp-Web-Services-AuthenticationService.svc' does not exist.`

Researching that led to finding [this forum post](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/218547.aspx/2/10#) which suggests creating a dummy .svc file with the name/path it is looking for.  The result:

- `The service '/ClientBin/DBCRM-Web-Services-AuthenticationService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The ending bracket '&gt;' for the 'ServiceHost' directive is missing in the '.svc' file..`

The details of the above error aren't largely important as it was a blank .svc file I supplied.  It merely served to confirm that fact that the project was indeed dependent on it

Here's the kicker... the working version **DOES NOT** contain this file either, yet it does not throw an exception.

Searching for any reference to needing the service surprisingly turned up a result in both solutions.  Both `MyApp.Web.g.cs`files are identical (ran a CSDiff) and both contain the line:

- `public AuthenticationContext() : 
              this(new WebDomainClient<IAuthenticationServiceContract>(new Uri("DBCRM-Web-Services-AuthenticationService.svc", UriKind.Relative)))
      {
      }`

Both have the same package/deploy settings.  I am deploying to a file system, then copying the files over to IIS on my host server.

Questions:

1. Where is a setting that makes this .svc file a requirement?  It's clearly not needed in version A, but is in version B.  Again, file `MyApp.Web.g.cs`is the only reference to it, and it exists in both versions.
2. `MyApp.Web.g.cs` is a generated file.  What service in Visual Studio 2010 creates this file?  Also, can I modify it to not include the call to the `.svc` file in question?

I'm going to start merging the two solutions together to see at which point the .svc file becomes neccessary.  Any ideas in the meantime would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

WCF Ria Services registers an HttpModule in order to manage the wcf ria services calls. When the request arrive to the server that module read the url and understand which service to instantiate and which method to call. So it's absolutely normal that you don't find any .svc file
Don't mess with the .g.cs your problem isn't here.
Take a look at your web.config file, you should find rows like this

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
...
</system.web>
```

and this

```
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </modules>
...
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I'm not sure how this is overly helpful?  Both the working and non-working versions have those exact lines in their respective web.config's.  Were you presuming the non-working version was missing them?  Bryan

Comment: My point was about to don't mess with client or the file.svc.
if the DomainServiceModule registration is fine, then your problem reside either on the DomainService instatiation, (take a look at your constructor) in the retrieval method (db error maybe ?) or even in the serialization. Take a look also at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129738/load-operation-failed-for-query-login-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-no

Comment: I guess I'll start looking elsewhere in the projects for inconsistencies.  I've seen that question before, and a few like it that are generally unresolved, hence why I decided to make this new one.  All that question suggests is error tracing, which I already mentioned I am doing.  If you have any other thoughts, please let me know! Bryan

Comment: If you can use the debugger, attach it and make sure to select to break on both managed and unmanaged exceptions.
Also, override the OnError on your domainservice, if the error happens inside the domainservice, this method get called.
A bit dumb, I know, but I've solved most of my problem with RIA 404 like that

Answer (score 0):

Besides making sure that the "DomainServiceModule" entries are present in Web.Config as stated above, another thing is that RIA requires ASP .NET compatibility mode to be enabled. Here is a link to Microsoft's deployment guide for RIA:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426912(v=vs.91).aspx

In the third paragraph of the "Configure the Web Server" section, it states that you need the following in your Web.Config file:

<system.serviceModel>
    ...
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    ...
</system.serviceModel>

When this is missing, you get the behavior described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do any of this make sure the regular `bin` folder is actually deployed containing your actual code.

I was deploying with MSDEPLOY to a new server and it did not deploy bin folder. You're not going to get anywhere without that!