# Load Operation failed for query 'Login'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0, entity-framework-5

I'm working with Siverlight 5.0, RIA Services and Entity framework in my project.

When I deploy the application using VS, the application runs fine. However, when I use a web deployment project to publish the application, the first call to a RIA services service on the same system fails. An error similar to this is produced:

> Load Operation failed for query 'Login'. The remote server returned an
>   error: NotFound

I guess, the last message is not enough to get the concrete error. Suggest me what to do to provide you more information. I'm getting this error for two days and I'm getting desperate.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd do is to [enable WCF tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx), and then [installing Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to get more information about the communication.  Every communication error with Silverlight comes back as NotFound, so your only real hope as far as the request/response itself goes is to have Fiddler give you a little extra insight.  WCF tracing will hopefully give you some more info on what's happening on the server end.  Finally, if possible, drop a debugger on the published application and insert a breakpoint to step through the issue.

That should hopefully give you more visibility on both the server and client side, with Fiddler giving you insight as to the communication that happens in between.

These sorts of errors are probably the biggest, or at least most common headache to working with Silverlight.  Best of luck.

Comment: When the message is showed, Fiddler shows on my site with red color: ERROR 404 what does it mean?

Comment: @DarfZon Http 404 is the standard [not found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)!  It would imply that the web service or other resource you're trying to access does not actually exist on the server.  If you're sure that it is, make sure the server is configured to direct traffic to the appropriate area.  You might also take another look at your deployment procedure.  Something's not being done properly, that's for sure, because it can't find the page/service/resource you're asking it to find.

Comment: Agree with YYY, WCF Tracing it's a good idea. Also, consider that a  an error in the constructor of your DomainServices will bring you the 404 message. Thai is a quite common situation. 
Another issue that can occurs rely on your web.config: have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13098530/363198 and check it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

RIA services can be a bit of a pain for this - it likes to return 404 whenever it can't do something...

You might find you have a deployment issue.  RIA services dynamically creates the endpoints from the assemblies it has access to.  Hopefully you know which assembly it is that is failing to load - if so, check your deployment directory to make sure the assembly is there, and use Fuslogvw to check whether there is an assembly binding issue.